# Python scikit-learn install build error using pip and setup code run

Tags: python, installation, scikit-learn

I am having quite a bit of trouble using scikit-learn on Python.
Below are the methods that I have already tried/what I have done.

1. I went to command window and installed via pip. It seems like it was successful.

```
C:\Users\ikim1>pip install -U scikit-learn
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\users\ikim1\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\ikim1\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.1.0 in c:\users\ikim1\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.6 in c:\users\ikim1\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.22.3)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\ikim1\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.1.0)
```

I know there are pip and pip3, so I tried both and both of them give me the above message, so I am going to guess that they are ok.

2. After the install I went to Python, tried to use scikit, but I got the below message.

```
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build:
setup.py                  _check_build.cp310-win_amd64.pyd__init__.py
__pycache__
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

I realized that there are setup.py files here (as you can already erd from the above error message) : C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\sklearn__check_build

However when I run that setup file, I get the error at the bottom.

```
C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build>python setup.py install
non-existing path in '.': '_check_build.pyx'
running install
running build
running config_cc
INFO: unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
INFO: build_src
INFO: building extension "__check_build._check_build" sources
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\setup.py", line 21, in <module>
    setup(**configuration(top_path="").todict())
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 58, in run
    r = old_install.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 568, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 61, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 144, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 161, in build_sources
    self.build_extension_sources(ext)
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 324, in build_extension_sources
    sources, py_files = self.filter_py_files(sources)
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 391, in filter_py_files
    return self.filter_files(sources, ['.py'])
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 400, in filter_files
    (base, ext) = os.path.splitext(source)
  File "C:\Users\ikim1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ntpath.py", line 204, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

I also tried to install from Anaconda3, but it is still giving me the same message in Python when I try to use it.

I am fairly new to Python usage, so can someone walk me through this issue?

Comment: How did you "go to Python and try to use scikit"? You don't need to run that script once you've (correctly) installed scikit-learn. You can also try to reinstall `scikit-learn`, just in case that helps.

Comment: I tried to use train_test_split() and SMOTE function and those errors came up. I did try reinstall but it did not work.